# python unittest assertion error function is not function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a common function that takes a value and returns a lambda function ref:

```py
def formatter(val):
    return lambda x: x == val
```

I'm trying to unit test that the return type is of a function.

```py
from types import FunctionType
from unittest import TestCase
class Test(TestCase):
   def test_func(test_cases):
     func = formatter(2)
     self.assertIsInstance(type(func), FunctionType)
```

But I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: <class 'function'> is not an instance of <class 'function'>
```

Comment: Do `assert callable(func)`.

Comment: You probably meant to write either `self.assertIsInstance(func, FunctionType)` or `self.assertEqual(type(func), FunctionType)`. The `IsInstance`-part of your assertion already type-ifys `func` under the hood for comparison

Comment: @Felk yep thanks! looks like I meant the latter. I wanted to make sure that the value of the return is of type function, so FUNC = FUNC, assert equal makes sense